# How to pass a List to a constructor of a new object using java lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, refactoring, collectors

I have a problem where **I want to convert a list of POJOs into DTOs and pass them into a wrapper object which is then returned**. Consider this ***working*** piece of code:

```
List<Device> devices = dbService.getDevices(...);
List<DeviceDTO> devicesDTO = new ArrayList<DeviceDTO>();
for (Device d : devices) {
   devicesDTO.add(convertToDTO(d));
}

WrapperDTO wrapper = new WrapperDTO(devicesDTO);
```

I am looking for a way to rewrite this into smaller, maybe more elegant, piece of code using Java lambda expressions. This is what I have done so far. I can do the conversion from POJOs to DTOs but I am struggling to pass the list of DTOs to the constructor of a new wrapper object.

```
List<Device> devices = dbService.getDevices(...);
List<DeviceDTO> devicesDTO = devices.stream().map(d -> convertToDTO(d)).collect(Collectors.toList());

WrapperDTO wrapper = new WrapperDTO(devicesDTO);
```

**How could I get it even shorter a one-liner, something like this?**

```
WrapperDTO wrapper = devices.stream()........collect( () -> WrapperDTO:new);
```

Obviously, the last piece is not working but that is something I would like to achieve. Any suggestions? Thank you my friends:)

Comment: wrapper = new WrapperDTO(devices.stream()...). But will that make the code more readable? That's what you should strive for. Not reducing the numbers of lines of code at all cost.

Comment: I agree with you, sometimes the shorter code is not the best code. But here I am being just curious of what may be possible to go. Gathering ideas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use `collectingAndThen` collector to solve it in one fell swoop. Use the `toList` collector as the downstream collector and pass the `WrapperDTO::new` constructor reference as the finisher function. Here's how it looks.

```
final WrapperDTO wrapper = devices.stream()
    .map(d -> convertToDTO(d))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), WrapperDTO::new));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

**There is a naughty secret:** write a `map` function for `List`.

Stash that little one away, and then all you need is:

```
WrapperDTO wrapper = new WrapperDTO(map(devices, MyClass::convertToDTO));
```

Don't tell the streams cool kids.

`map` for `List` should look something like:

```
public static <T, R> List<R> map​(
    List<T> source, Function<? super T,​? extends R> mapper
) {
    List<R> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T item : source) {
        result.add(mapper.apply(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```